# RESTEasy Reactive and Content-Length in Response headers

Tags: java, resteasy, quarkus

We have a quarkus application, which uses `quarkus-resteasy-reactive` and `quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson` extensions.

Is it possible to have the `Content-Length` header populated for every **response**?

If we have a resource endpoint like this:

```java
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
public PersonDTO get(String id) {
    return service.get(id);
}
```

then the response would have the `transfer-encoding: chunked` header.

We don't use any reactive constructs.

With the 'RESTEasy-classic' (`quarkus-resteasy`) extension the `Content-Length` header is always present.

Going back to `quarkus-resteasy` would require rewriting all exception mappers and we'd like to avoid that.

Is it possible to stop chunking of responses? They are really small.

Is there a configuration property to increase some buffer to force `Content-Length` calculation upfront?

Increasing `quarkus.resteasy.vertx.response-buffer-size`
and `quarkus.resteasy-reactive.input-buffer-size` have no effect.

**Update 1**:
A sample application, illustrating the issue, can be found here:
https://github.com/roman-svystun/resteasy-reactive-content-length

It turns out, the `Content-Length` is present in the json response, but only if the body size is less than **256** bytes.

If the json body size is 256 bytes or more, we only get `transfer-encoding: chunked`.

**Update 2**:
In https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/6fc8791e7b304612429eade2fcc0d460a14905c3/independent-projects/resteasy-reactive/server/vertx/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/reactive/server/vertx/ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.java#L228-L240

the `Content-Length` header is only set if server response fits into a buffer which has 256 bytes of initial capacity. If it does not fit, response is set to be `chunked`.
It would be nice to have a configuration property for these 256 bytes to be able to increase them.

Comment: Do you have an example application that I can check?

Comment: @geoand, I've updated the question with the link to the sample app. Thank you, for expressing some interest.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and have a look in a few days. Feel free to ping me if I forget

Comment: I opened https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/22585 to track this. Thanks for your time to report this

Comment: Thank you for your incomparably larger time and effort to provide a configuration option/solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in Quarkus itself, starting with version `2.7.0.CR1`.

The default buffer size has been increased from around 256 to 8191 bytes.

So, `Content-Length` response is present in responses with up to 8190 bytes in size.

Additionally, there is a configuration property, which can be used to increase or decrease the buffer size, e.g.:

`quarkus.resteasy-reactive.output-buffer-size=16384`